# Countable nouns must always have determiners or should be plural?

Tags: countable-nouns

I've learnt countable nouns must always have determiners or should be plural. However, the construction pattern **between A and B** seems to be an exception.

> There are even stories of half-trained elephant calves who have
> refused to feed and pined to death when by some unavoidable
> circumstance they have been deprived of their own trainer. Such
> extreme cases should probably be taken with a grain of salt, but
> they do underline the general principle that the relationship **between
> elephant and mahout** is the key to successful training.  (This is written by Richard Carrington.)

Maybe the pattern **"A and/or/nor B"** is also an exception.

> **Mother and child** form a close attachment. (This is in a Collins dictionary)

> **Elephant and mahout** form a close attachment. (I wrote this.)

> It's not a fit night out for **man or/nor beast**. (This is in Merriam-Webster's Advanced Learner's Dictionary) (I understand man is used as an uncountable noun here, but beast is always countable.)

Comment: They are 'bare' NP's, the type that don't require a determiner. See here [link](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/315952/how-can-we-parse-naked-shingles-in-dover-beach#comment592904_315952).

Comment: I think the principle behind whether we include a determiner or not is to do with the ***meaning** [in context]* rather than some particular sequence of words such as ***between X and Y***. Basically, it's when X and Y are "universal / archetypal" references, far removed from any *specific* instances of X and Y. Consider (1) *It's good for man to respect God* as a "universal" observation, where the equally valid (2) *It's good for **a** man to respect **his** god* has a more "localised, parochial" flavour.

Comment: (Also consider the endless speculation about whether Armstrong ***did or should have*** included an article in [*That’s one small step for {**A**} man, one giant leap for mankind*](https://whyy.org/articles/armstrongs-famous-one-small-step-quote-explained/#:~:text=radio%20heard%20this%3A-,%E2%80%9CThat's%20one%20small%20step%20for%20man%2C%20one%20giant%20leap%20for,didn't%20hear%20it.%E2%80%9D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*not man nor beast* is a non-countable use of *beast*. A dictionary's assignment of countability to a noun isn't absolute. See:

[nouns and countability](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/277514708_Nouns_and_Countability)
"The customary disjunctive marking of lexical entries for English nouns as [± countable] does not match the fact that the majority can be used both countably and uncountably in different NP environments: this binary opposition is characteristic not of the nouns, but of the NP's which they head. "

I'm tired now; give me a coffee.

Comment: I fail to understand this sentence:  this binary opposition is characteristic not of the nouns, but of the NP's which they head. Can you paraphrase and give an example? Here is my guess: "this binary opposition" refers to the dichotomy between countable and non-countable. Nouns don't have this dichotomy, but noun phrases have? So a noun phrase is either  countable or non-countable? Is "elephant and mahout" such a noun phrase?

Comment: "Elephant and mahout" is a noun phrase consisting of two coordinated nouns. According to this reference https://books.google.com/books?id=qlxDqB4ldx4C&pg=PA87&dq=nouns+with+count+and+non-count+interpretations&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwin692Qw5n4AhUZX80KHWYTD84Q6AF6BAgJEAI#v=onepage&q=nouns%20with%20count%20and%20non-count%20interpretations&f=false "Nouns that have only a count interpretation or only a non-count interpretation are in a minority. Most nouns can be used with either type of interpretation." The reference gives examples of nouns used both ways.